# javascript new Date(2015,01,29) returns completely wrong date

Tags: javascript, date

I am running this Javascript code on FireFox console:

```
> new Date(2015,01,29)
< Date 2015-03-01T03:00:00.000Z
```

I create a new date object with the date "2015-01-29" and the object instead saves the date "2015-03-01".

It also happens if I change the 'hour':

```
> new Date(2015,01,29,12)
< Date 2015-03-01T15:00:00.000Z
```

What's going on? I am completely lost on this.

How do I fix this 'bug'?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Moth stats at 0, more informations here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new Date('2015,01,29') vs new Date(2015,01,29)

You are not using date input as string.

String format uses months as you would in real life: 01 - January.
Number format looks at months as indexes 0 - January.

Comment: I understand it now!!! In new Date(2015,01,29) the month is interpreted as being equal to 2, because that's how Date.getMonth() returns a month. But this won't happen when you pass the argument as a string.

Answer (score 5):

Because the month-value starts with 0 (zero) `new Date(2015,01,29)` would be 29 of february which is not possible.

So for 2015-01-29 use 0 for the month parameter

```
new Date(2015,0,29)
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)

Comment: Still strange that it translates to march and not to february

Comment: @MarkSmit There is no 29th of February in 2015 so it takes the day after Feb 28th which is March 1st.

Comment: I guess the best way is to just pass the date as a string and not have to deal with this nasty month change. By the way, if you pass `new Date('2015,02,29')` you still get the next "available" date `Date 2015-03-01T03:00:00.000Z`.

Comment: Oh days start counting from 0 too injavascript?

Comment: @MarkSmit No. If they did then it would return March 2nd.

Comment: @Mark Smit No. Only months